# Does BluetoothLeAdvertiser work on a Nexus 4 with Android 5.0?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth, nexus-4

I know Android 5.0 supports BLE peripheral mode, but i am not so sure if it works on Nexus 4 with Android 5.0.

The QuickBeacon app is not compatible with Nexus 4, which is suspicious.

Comment: No. Works on Nexus6, Nexus9 but not any Nexus before.

Comment: Thanks. Post this as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLE peripheral mode only works on Nexus 6/9 but not older Nexus devices.

Someone from Google explained the situation in comment #52 of the following issue in AOSP
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1570